# How to adjust the vertical position of the word "Text" to the center?

Tags: vertical-alignment

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{My Caption}
\label{my-label}\smallskip
\begin{tabular}{c|c c c}
\small{Text} & \small{Qgc} & \small{Qgc} & \small{Qgc}  \\  & \small{{[}MVar{]}} & \small{{[}MVar{]}} & \small{{[}MVar{]}}  \\ \hline
\small{A}           & \small{-100}                        & \small{100.00}                  & \small{100}                         \\
\small{B}           & \small{-100}                        & \small{100}                     & \small{100}                         \\
\small{C}           & \small{-100}                        & \small{100}                     & \small{100}                         \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just some notes on your table:

1. Instead of repeating `\small` everywhere, just add `small` at the beginning. Also `\small` is a switch not a command, it has no `{}`.
2. Columns 2 through 4 are mainly numeric data, so it is best put in math-mode by adding `>{$}c<{$}` as their column specification.
3. The same column header `Qgc [MVar]` is repeated three times, so just `\multicolumn{3}{c}{Qgc [MVar]}` will suffice.
4. Removing all vertical rules and using `booktabs` can further improve the readability.
5. Better off leave LaTeX decide the best place to put your table instead of forcing this here `[h]` specifier. At a final revision, though, you can move the table code part up or down in text to change the position where the table appears.

.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\small\centering
\caption{My Caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{@{}c *3{>{$}c<{$}}@{}}
\toprule
Text     & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Qgc [MVar]}   \\ \cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(l){2-4}
A        & -100       & 100.00      & 100   \\
B        & -100       & 100         & 100   \\
C        & -100       & 100         & 100   \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 3):

A comment up front: You're not using the `\small` directive correctly: It does *not* take an argument. Hence, inside a table cell, `\small{Qgc}` does the same as `\small Qgc`. Better to cut down on code clutter, right?

Second, since the contents of every single cell of the `tabular` environment are supposed to be rendered in `\small`, it's preferable to simply issue a `\small` directive *before* starting the `tabular` environment (and removing the `\small` directives from the individual cells).

Third, if you're going to make the contents of the `tabular` environment smaller, it's a good idea, typographically speaking, to make the associated `\caption` material smaller as well. An easy way to achieve this is to load the `caption` package and to issue a suitable `\captionsetup` directive immediately before the `\caption` statement.

Do also remember to typeset negative numbers in math mode to generate typographically appropriate `-` (math-mode "minus") signs, rather than simple dashes.

Last (and possibly least, in my opinion), use a `\multirow` statement (provided by the `multirow` package) to center the label "Text" vertically.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering

\caption{Original version}
\label{version:one}
\begin{tabular}{c|c c c}
\small{Text} & \small{Qgc} & \small{Qgc} & \small{Qgc}  \\  
             & \small{{[}MVar{]}} & \small{{[}MVar{]}} & \small{{[}MVar{]}}  \\ 
\hline
\small{A}           & \small{-100}     & \small{100.00}    & \small{100}   \\
\small{B}           & \small{-100}     & \small{100}       & \small{100}   \\
\small{C}           & \small{-100}     & \small{100}       & \small{100}   \\
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\captionsetup{font=small}
\caption{Modified Version}
\label{version:two}
\small
\begin{tabular}{c|c c c}
\multirow{2}{*}{Text} &   Qgc  &   Qgc  &   Qgc   \\  
                      & [MVar] & [MVar] & [MVar]  \\ 
\hline
A       & $-100$  & 100.00  & 100  \\
B       & $-100$  & 100     & 100  \\
C       & $-100$  & 100     & 100  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

A solution without multirows nor multicolumns but with `m` columns.

The second table deal with the case that other columns must be of another type (with decimal alignment in this case, note the correct sign in "-100" with the `S` columns of  the `siunitx` package) using a `\parbox` to allow line breaks in the headers.

Note also that in this case the column width could be due to the `\parbox` width, or to the space reserved for digits before/after the decimal point (case of the example).

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,siunitx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{T}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3em}}
\newcolumntype{U}{S[table-format=4.2]}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{1em}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{My Caption}
\label{my-label}
\small
\begin{tabular}{TTTT}\toprule
Text & Qgc [MVar] & Qgc [MVar] & Qgc [MVar] \\\midrule
A & -100 & 100.00 & 100\\
B & -100 & 100    & 100\\
C & -100 & 100    & 100\\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{My Caption}
\begin{tabular}{TUUU}\toprule
Text & 
\parbox{3em}{\centering Qgc [MVar]} &
\parbox{3em}{\centering Qgc [MVar]} &
\parbox{3em}{\centering Qgc [MVar]}\\\midrule
A & -100 & 100.00 & 100\\
B & -100 & 10    & 100\\
C & -100 & 1.0    & 100\\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution by using multirow package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
%opening
\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{My Caption}
\label{my-label}\smallskip
\begin{tabular}{c|c c c}
\multirow{2}{*}{\small{Text}} & \small{Qgc} & \small{Qgc} & \small{Qgc}  \\  & \small{{[}MVar{]}} & \small{{[}MVar{]}} & \small{{[}MVar{]}}  \\ \hline
\small{A}           & \small{-100}                        & \small{100.00}                  & \small{100}                         \\
\small{B}           & \small{-100}                        & \small{100}                     & \small{100}                         \\
\small{C}           & \small{-100}                        & \small{100}                     & \small{100}                         \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Move `Text` into position with `\raisebox`, or use `\makecell`'s default placement (vertical/horizontal `c`entre):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{c c c c}
    \toprule
    \raisebox{-.5\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{Text} 
            &   Qgc  &   Qgc  &   Qgc  \\  
            & [MVar] & [MVar] & [MVar] \\ 
    \midrule
    A       & $-100$  & 100.00  & 100  \\
    B       & $-100$  & 100     & 100  \\
    C       & $-100$  & 100     & 100  \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}

  \bigskip

  \begin{tabular}{c c c c}
    \toprule
    Text    & \makecell{Qgc \\{}[MVar]} & \makecell{Qgc \\{}[MVar]} & \makecell{Qgc \\{}[MVar]} \\
    \midrule
    A       & $-100$  & 100.00  & 100  \\
    B       & $-100$  & 100     & 100  \\
    C       & $-100$  & 100     & 100  \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```